By default , port 80 is open on google cloud compute engine VM. How to close it?
I am new to google cloud. I created a VM on google cloud. And installed apache2 web server. And added some dummy code in '''echo "Hello World" > /var/www/html/index.html'''. And started the apache2 server. When I did "curl http://" I get the http response. While I did not click on "Allow HTTP traffic" or "Allow HTTPS traffic" while creating the VM. But port 80 is open. How to close port 80.
Thanks,
Sachin

Not positive, but I am pretty sure that installing apache2 automatically opens port 80.

@s4D_t0y Apache installation cannot affect Google Cloud firewall.

On what computer did you run curl?

Your question is a set of statements but not a set of facts. Please update your question to include the specific commands that you used to create the VM, install Apache and access the server. It would be useful to include relevant additional information such as whether this is project is part of an organization in which other people are operating. We're trying to avoid "Oh, it turns out that Chris in Finance enabled port 80 on every VM in our org!"
